# jqGrid and Compatibility View mode in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid, ie8-compatibility-mode

In my last project I've used jqGrid 3.8.2, jQuery 1.4.4 and jquery-ui-1.8.10.
The company I work for still uses IE8 as a web broswer so in my development I always test with that platform. 
I've noticed today that a jqGrid is rendered properly when I test everything on my machine (winXP) using the Visual Studio (2010) ASP.NET Development Server:
[image: Good]

As you can see the selection is perfect and the header is ok.

When I copy everything on the production server (Win 2003 + IIS6.0) the same form renders in a funny way.

[image: Bad]

As you can see now the row selection is not working properly and I've got these strange arrows in the header. 
PS: I am using the same computer and browser to render the same page.
PPS: Obviously, if I use a different (professional ;-) ) browser (mozilla, safari, opera, chrome) everything works properly.

Comment: Does it have to do with the server that's serving up your page? (AKA, take a look at the produced output of both the development environment and the production server using a tool like Firebug/ChromDevTools - make sure they match.)

Comment: @JasCav, I've checked the output and it is exactly the same. Same content etc etc. Where else should I look? PS: I am using firebugs but with FF everything looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried looking at it using IE8's developer toolbar?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I'll post a reply with an extended answer.

Comment: Excellent! Looking forward to seeing the answer as I am a frequent user of jqGrid and have never seen this problem before.

Comment: Same problem arise with me I can not load the data in the grid and when the compatibility icon is clicked then only it is displaying the data. I am using IE9 for displaying the grid. It works very well with IE8 and earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some strange reason IE8 sets the "compatibility view" for all the intranet sites:
[image: Compantibility View Settings]

So I couldn't see the "compatibility view" button next to my URL bar.
I had to go to Tools - Compantibility View Settings and uncheck the flag "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".
No my site (intranet site) is shown in standard mode and everything works as expected.
Thanks Microsoft cause, once again, I've wasted a few hours for your silliness.

**UPDATE**

As Oleg suggested you can add these tags to your configuration file (ASP.NET and MVC):

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

but this only works in **IIS7** cause `<system.webServer>` is not used by **IIS6**.
A better way to achieve the same results - and it works for me - is to put a **META** tag in the master page in the **HEAD** section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I've tested it and it works even if you have "*Display intranet sites in Compatibility View*" active.

Comment: +1 for very interesting information. Probably I have to consider to use " X-UA-Compatible" with "IE=edge" or "IE=8" or "IE=9; IE=8;" in the master page to have to such problems. Probably the way with `<configuration><system.webServer><httpProtocol><customHeaders><clear /><add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=7" />` can be even better (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx#Servers)). In any way I will look at the setting more carefully.

Comment: That's very interesting Oleg. I didn't know that.

Comment: @LeftyX: I made some tests yesterday and can find an example where setting `"X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8"` in web.config and usage "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" gives me **not the same results** as clearing of the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View". I seen that `"X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8"` in web.config worked, but it did **less** then the clearing of the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View". So be careful with the information what write Microsoft about different ways of the managing of the "Compatibility View".

Comment: Thanks Oleg, you've been really helpful. Actually I need to work on that cause I can't tell the IT manager that he has to change the setting on 80 clients :-s

Comment: @LeftyX: Exactly the same problem I have also (but with some 10 000 of computers :-)). So I will also try different ways to solve or at least reduce the problem with the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View". I will inform you here about it if I would find some interesting results and I ask you to do the same. OK?

Comment: Thank Oleg. Helpful as always. I'll be investigating the issue.I'll keep you posted on that.

Comment: @LeftyX: It seems to me that I fond the difference between "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" and the usage `"X-UA-Compatible"`  or `<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="..." />`. If you use "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" you will have both `$.browser.version`="8.0" and document.documentMode=8 or both "7.0" and 7. If you use "X-UA-Compatible" to force IE8 mode, but you will have you are still in the "Compatibility View" mode, then `$.browser.version`="7.0", but document.documentMode=8. In my code I tested for `$.browser.version`. Now I test document.documentMode also.

Comment: Great Oleg.I was busy with some other stuff and I didn't have time to test these things. I'll get back to it next week. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LeftyX: You are welcome! If you will find out also something interesting later, please let me know. The subject still are very interesting for me.

Comment: @Oleg, I've updated my answer with a simple, efficient solution. I've tested it and it seem to work. What do you think?

Comment: @LeftyX: This is almost the same what I currently use myself after the discussion with you and some tests. The IIS 6 is not more important for me, so I decide to use `customHeaders` way and have `<meta>` commented with server comment so I can switch to anather way any time. The only real difference to my configuration is that I use "IE=edge" to use IE9 mostly effectively. The problem is that some CSS (rotated texts to -90 grad) which I use are implemented in IE9 much better. My site are tested with IE8 and IE9 so I prefer the "IE=edge" setting.

Comment: Same problem arise with me I can not load the data in the grid and when the compatibility icon is clicked then only it is displaying the data. I am using IE9 for displaying the grid. It works very well with IE8 and earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks much more as the error in deployment. I mean that either some files (for example from the `images` subdirectory of the jQuery UI) are not copied or copied or you use somewhere somewhere absolute and not relative paths. So some files could not be found after the deployment on the server.

You can try to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see which files could not be loaded during the page loding.

Comment: Same problem arise with me I can not load the data in the grid and when the compatibility icon is clicked then only it is displaying the data. I am using IE9 for displaying the grid. It works very well with IE8 and earlier versions of IE.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: After writing of the answer I wrote some comments to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5263387/315935). I use personally `"IE=edge"` mode of `"X-UA-Compatible"` on all productive pages. Do you tried to use this? Do you have still an issue or your problem is solved? If you need help from me you should prepare a demo which can be used to reproduce the problem and post it in new answer. Then I could analyse the problem and probably gives you some recommendations.

Comment: I can not do the same because it will be used to the end client and I can not say to client that make your IE compatible. And one more thing is that my problem is that I can not load the JSON data into the Grid in IE9 only, but when I make compatible to the previous version then only the data is displayed.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: If you use meta "X-UA-Compatible" with "IE=edge" you switch off from compatibility view to native IE9 mode **only for the page**. It is almost the same as to define using `<!DOCTYPE>` that you need that web browser render the page as HTML 4 or HTML5 page. So if you use not HTML5 on the page you can just include `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` at the beginning of your page to solve the compatibility mode problem.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Loading of JSON in jqGrid isn't depend on compatibility mode. I suppose that the origin of your problem is somewhere else. To say more I have to see the code of grid and the data which you described.

Comment: As I said the data is displayed in IE8 or earlier but not with IE9.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: If the grid not display the data, it's not the same as "I can not load the JSON data into the Grid in IE9". Either the problem is **loading of data** or **to display it**. What I wrote before mean that I don't think that you have any problem *during loading* of data.

Comment: Data is displayed in IE8 and other browsers but not in IE9 thats my problem.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: As I wrote before you posted too few information. The problem is in JavaScript, HTML code which you use or in the JSON data. So till you don't provide the information I'm unable to help you.

Comment: You want to say `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> ` will not help me ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: I want to say that you can try to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. It could help, but if it helps you not I can't gives you any other tips till I get more information about the problem. You should understand that I can't find an error in the code which I didn't seen.

Comment: But can u explain what is the meaning of this tag and why it is used and what are the parameters and values are describing ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#SetMode). I know from you only that if you switch off the compatibility view for your page the page will be displayed correctly. If you include the `meta` IE will display the page in the mode directly at the page load.