# Issue with the Navigation Bar in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, navigation

I'm facing a problem with my configuration of jqGrid. I'm trying to activate the navigation bar using this configuration:

```js
$(function(){ 
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'test.xml',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Name','Last Name', 'Id Nbr'],
        colModel :[ 
           {name:'name', index:'name', width:200}, 
           {name:'lastName', index:'lastName', width:200}, 
           {name:'idnbr', index:'idnbr', width:60}
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        sortname: 'name',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        loadonce: true,
        sortable: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        height: '100%',
        width: '800',
        caption: 'My first grid'
    }); 
}); 
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
```

And my HTML code looks like this:

```html
<table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div>
```

I've read a lot of answers here at Stackoverflow about how to configure the navigation bar, but i can't get my add, edit, delete, find and refresh buttons in the bar, only the pages handle.

I would like to know if I'm missing something on my code or what, because I've tried to get this buttons but no results until now.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you call `navGrid` **outside** of `$(function(){/*it should be here*/});`. So the method will be called not only before the grid is created, but probably event before the `<table>` and `<page>` elements are placed (loaded) on the page.

Just move the call of `navGrid` one line above inside of `$(function(){/*it should be here*/});` (which is the same as `$(document).ready(function () {/*the same code inside*/})`, see [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) and your code will work as expected.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Thanks for your response. Actually with that, I've made my grid to work and the buttons finally are on the navigation bar! Thanks again

Comment: I've actually test my grid on IE8 and the Navgrid is giving me some problems (The grid dissapered). If I remove all the navGrid, my grid appears again on my page, but it stills disappered if I left the navGrid option.After debugging in IE, I've realize that I have a JS error. After fix it, The pager appears but the icons of the navigation bar disappered. Do you have any idea why is this probably happening? Thanks

Comment: Well, it seems that using the tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` works perfectly. In any case, is this the real solution for the problem? Thanks

Comment: @ABottoni: Last time I try to include always in my demos `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to be sure that IE compatibility mode don't disturb (see comments to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5263387/315935)). To be sure whether it's real solution of your problem I have to see (to reproduce) the problem.