# Jqgrid is not loading in IE 8 32 bit. Working fine in IE 8 64 Bit

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to test the Jqgrid in **IE-8 32 BIT** version and it is not loading the grid totally. When i check in developer tools i can see all scripts are loaded. Once i click on the start debugging button all scripts were gone.

It is working fine in **IE-8 64 BIT** version.

I have referred @Oleg answers and set mentioned settings in Web.Config, But no use.

[jqGrid and Compatibility View mode in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262775/jqgrid-and-compatibility-view-mode-in-ie8)

I have tried to add below mentioned code. But nothing works out.

```
  <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

below is the details Oleg.

Jqgrid Version :  jqGrid  4.6.0 , 
HTML : 5 []

[image]

Anybody please help me.

Note: It is not showing any syntax or any error in the browser.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

[image]

**IE 8 32 BIT**
[image]
**IE 8 64 BIT**
[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which HTML version `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` you use? Do you see that HTML page with other elements are loaded? Are *other* JavaScripts run correctly on the page? Do you have the same effect if you opens **local** jqGrid without usage IIS?

Comment: @oleg,  >> Do you have the same effect if you opens local jqGrid without usage IIS? --> I don't know how to test this. But i have only Jqgird in my page. For other answers i have updated in Question.

Comment: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleLocalGrid_.htm) for example. Does it work on your test computers in IE-8 32 BIT and in IE-8 64 BIT?

Comment: I tried with above mentioned demo. Still no luck. Nothing displaying in the page. @oleg

Comment: Are you sure that Scripting is not blocked on the IE? Can you debug the page in Developer Tools? How the HTML page look like after executing jqGrid script? You should in any way **debug** what do IE8 32-bit. The information which you post is not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: I have uploaded the image in my question as UPDATE. Nothing showed in the page.@oleg

Comment: Why one see "WebForm.aspx" on the picture instead of "...simpleLocalGrid_.htm"? Can you just open [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleLocalGrid_.htm) directly on the computer which have problems?

Comment: Sorry. I have created a new page and inserted the demo content inside my page. Since i have to deploy the content into the server. and there is no access for public path to grab scripts . So i have downloaded and added to the new folder to map that. @oleg

Comment: Could you open **local static** HTML page on the computer? You can save all required JavaScripts in the same directory with HTML and to modify the HTML page so that it use *relative pathes* like `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You should understand that nobody can solve the problem for you because nobody knows what is wrong on the computer.

Comment: Surprise it is working fine if i open that as HTM as you suggested. don't know why it is not working if is in ASPX. @oleg

Comment: Now if you have one HTML page with working code and another HTML page with not working code you should slowly modify one page to be close to another one. If you do this step-by step you will find the reson of the problem. For example, if you said that one can't open free URL from the common place in Internet you should validate that the URLs to the scripts on your side are in trusted area. I suppose that you have **different IE configurations** on 32-bit and 64-bit computers.

Comment: Found something interesting. If I browse a file from hosted website **[www.stack.com\new\simpleLocalGrid_.htm]** is not wokring .. if I open the file from virtual path **[C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\new\simpleLocalGrid_.htm] ** it is working fine. @oleg

Comment: As I wrote before I suppose that you have some policy restriction in the IE configuration which prevent running scripts from "untrusted" sites and either the stackoverflow or http://ajax.googleapis.com/ and http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com from which the dependent scripts are loaded are not rusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BIG BIG thanks to you @oleg.

It is all working fine now after i added the site to the Trusted sites zone in Internet Explorer Setting.

***Trusted Sites Zone***

**This zone contains Web sites that you trust as safe (such as Web sites that are on your organization's intranet or that come from established companies in whom you have confidence). When you add a Web site to the Trusted Sites zone, you believe that files you download or that you run from the Web site will not damage your computer or data. By default, there are no Web sites that are assigned to the Trusted Sites zone, and the security level is set to Low.**